# Trying to Use a ForEach Loop to get a product version off of an .exe, then based on that version, execute a batch of functions

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, if-statement, foreach

Thanks in advance for taking a look. I just wanted to see what someone else might do to get this working correctly. Very new to PowerShell and Python, so I am just trying to live in it right now as I work.

This script is a little side project.

```
    function EXEversion {

    $prod1 = (Get-item "Path of exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    $prod2 = (Get-item "Path of exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    $prod3 = (Get-item "Path of exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    $prod3 = (Get-item "Path of exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
    $MyArray = @($prod1, $prod2, $prod3, $prod4)
```

See my Foreach loop below:

```
    foreach ($item in $MyArray){
        if ($item.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq 15.9...)
    {
    # Here is where my other list of functions would go that delete certain items #
    }

        }

    elseif ($item.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq 16.0)
        {
         # Other list of functions dedicated for if this specific version is found)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I know my indents and format is all wrong, I am super new to PS and still learning proper format. I think I may be close, and it does work to some extent, but not correctly and not the way it needs to. Just wanted to see what someone else might do instead.

Comment: HOW does it "not work the way it needs to"? please, add what you get and what you want to get to your Question to clarify what you mean. ///// i THINK you want to take a look at the `[version]` type instead of comparing strings.

Comment: I agree with @Lee_Dailey you should cast the result of `(Get-item "Path of exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion` to a type [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version) to compare as a whole `-eq [Version]'16.0'` or do something like `[version]$prod1.Major -eq 15 -and [version]$prod1.Minor -gt 8`

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear. The main issue I get with both my method and the method posted by Abraham, is that it tries to run each "if" statement 4 times for each exe path causing the code I put in after to execute incorrectly. I will post the full code with paths and product versions in a bit. I am using different versions of visual studio as the exe's and using Write-host after the "if" statements to tell me if that product version was found or not. I will post full code before end of day.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, unlike Python, PowerShell doesn't really care about indentations. As far as where to place the opening and closing of a scriptblock, that's really up to you whether on the same line as a condition, or a new line.

```
if ($that -eq $this)
{
    # This method is quite common as it helps the reader -
    # see where the chunk of code begins, and ends.
}

if ($this -eq $that) {
    # This method is common as well
}
```

Indentation can go a long way in helping yourself out as it makes code easier to follow. A good rule is to indent code that falls into the previous expression such as:

```
if ($that -eq $this) {
    $Variable = CodeTo-Execute -Goes 'Here'
        if ($Variable -eq 'something') {
            'executeMe!'
        }
}

# Nothing is really stopping you from doing this either,
# as it becomes harder to read/manage:
if ($this -eq $that)
        {
            # Code here
                #  more code here
        # some code here
    }
```

**Note**: Remember, indentation as such only applies to powershell when comparing it vs Python. These aren't really rules you need to abide, but rather good practices you should consider getting into a habit of doing.

. . .back to your code snippet, here's an approach I would take:

```
$exePaths = @(
    "C:\Path\To\.exe1", 
    "C:\Path\To\.exe2",
    "C:\Path\To\.exe3",
    "C:\Path\To\.exe4",
    "C:\Path\To\.exe5"
)
    foreach ($Path in $exePaths)
    {
        $productVersion = (Get-Item -Path $Path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
        if ($productVersion -eq 15.9) {
            # code here
        } 
        elseif ($productVersion -eq 16.0) {
            # code here
        }
        else {
            # code here
        }
    }
```

this can easily be done with a *Switch* statement as well.